# Hide Textbox in Access Form and shift remaining columns over hidden textbox

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Is it possible to hide a textbox in an MS Access Form just like a column in an Excel sheet.

I can hide the textbox by doing

```
Me.Text48.Visible = False
```

but how would I visually move the remaining textboxes that are right of the hidden one to the position of the hidden one?

Comment: In my module [Form_ModernBox.cls](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernBox/blob/master/Form_ModernBox.cls) you can find the function `SetButtonSequence``which arranges buttons using an array, but it could just as well be textboxes.

Comment: Set textbox Left property, example: `.tbxBox1.Left = 200 'in twips, 1 inch = 1440 twips`. And if there is a detached label you want to align with textbox, also set its property.

Comment: Thank you both very much. I managed to do it with the left and top property as you sugested. If you want to post your comment as answer I'll accept it. @Gustav: that module is mad helpful, I'm going to use it at some point.

Comment: You can write answer to your own question and then accept it.